# How to call classic NetFramework library method from .Net Core project

Tags: import, asp.net-core, class-library

i have a very simple asp.net core project and a classlibrary built in .net framework 4.6.1
I have imported the library in the asp.net core project but i can't use it.
If in a controller (for example) i write:

using ClassLibrary1;

a popup appear saying:

namespace ClassLibrary1 WebApplication1.Net Framework 4.6.1 - Available WebApplication1.NetCoreApp,Version 1.0 - Not Available

How can i use my classlibrary object and method in asp.net core project?

---

Thank you for repling but not work for me.

Here is my project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassLibrary1": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.1",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

and here my project files
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0RBO.png)

but in Homecontroller i get this error
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSYyR.png)

whats wrong?

Comment: any solution to this problem? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Either your library should support **netcoreapp1.0** or your website should support net461 (or both). Update your project.json with :

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
    },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "type": "platform"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```